# Mysql Query Join Table on the most recent row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page of categories, they worked fine until I did a join.

The categories display like so:

> category 1-----------------------0----------0
> discussion 1   by someone
>
> category 2-----------------------0----------0
> discussion 2   by someoneelse

Now where it says discussion, I need to display the last discussion posted to that category based on it's `discussion_id`. I have tried `ORDER BY ... DESC` but it sorts by category names not the discussion names and posted by.

```
 $sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(d.cat_id) as count 
         FROM discussions as d 
         LEFT JOIN categories c ON (c.cat_id = d.cat_id) 
         RIGHT JOIN soldiers s ON (s.uid = d.discussion_poster) 
         GROUP BY d.cat_id";
 $result = query($sql);  

    
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) != false) {       
   $cat_id = $row['cat_id']; 
   $discussion_id = $row['discussion_id'];
   $cat_title = $row['cat_title'];
   $discussion_title = $row['discussion_title']; 
   $discussion_time = $row['discussion_time'];
   $count = $row['count'];
   $discussion_poster_id = $row['discussion_poster'];
   $discussion_poster = $row['soldier'];
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide more information of table like structure of your table, sample data etc;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "
SELECT *
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT MAX(discussion_id) discussion_id,
   COUNT(discussion_id) as count,
   cat_id
   FROM
   discussions
   GROUP BY
   cat_id
) as d1
ON (c.cat_id = d1.cat_id)
INNER JOIN discussions as d
ON (d1.discussion_id = d.discussion_id)
INNER JOIN soldiers s
ON (s.uid = d.discussion_poster)
GROUP BY d.cat_id";
```

Comment: trex005 still shows on categories with discussions and still don't update the link of last topic

Comment: I had a typo in first iteration, try again.

Comment: Note: There will not be a soldier if there is not a discussion, so a right join is messy.  I turned that into a left outer join as well.  Please try again.

Comment: trex005 I'm not worried about the categories displaying so much but I want the post of the most recent to display like it does there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109861/discussion-between-trex005-and-william).